# Inserting NULL into MySQL timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hibernate

I'm observing unexpected behavior with inserting/updating NULL in a MySQL timestamp column.

Consider the following statements.

```
create table temp(id int, hireDate timestamp default 0);
insert into temp (id) values(1);
insert into temp (id, hireDate) values(2, null);
select * from temp;
id  hireDate
-----------------------------
1   
2   2012-09-19 10:54:10.0
```

The first insert (when `hiredate` is not specified in the SQL, hireDate is `null(0)` which is expected.

However when an explicit null passed in SQL, the current date time is inserted which is unexpected.  Why does this happen?

Note: Hibernate uses second type of insert and hence it become an issue. How do I insert null into a timestamp column?

Comment: What is Hibernate? It is default behaviour of MySQL. Every time You update row also timestamp fields update automagically

Comment: default 0 is the key. without that it will still be NULL, instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 34, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

> In addition, you can initialize or update any TIMESTAMP column to the current date and time by assigning it a NULL value, unless it has been defined with the NULL attribute to permit NULL values.

In order to allow a TIMESTAMP to be nullable, create it using the NULL attribute, or alter the table and add the NULL attribute. In a create statement, it would resemble.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (tsvalue TIMESTAMP NULL, ... );
```

Inserting a ***NULL*** value into a ***TIMESTAMP*** field with the NULL attribute set will result in the field being set to NULL instead of to NOW().

Comment: what is the "Null" attribute?

Comment: Column with NULL attribute allows NULL values. NULL means value does not exist. For example, table people with columns name and job. Peter works as programmer so name value will be Peter and job value will be programmer. But Justin is unemployed so name value will be Justin but job value will be NULL as he doesn't have a job

Answer (score 11):

### You can insert and update NULL into a MySQL timestamp.

**Create the table:**

```
create table penguins(id int primary key auto_increment, the_time timestamp NULL);
```

**Insert some rows:**

```
insert into penguins(the_time) values (now());
insert into penguins(the_time) values (null);
insert into penguins(the_time) values (0);
insert into penguins(the_time) values ('1999-10-10 01:02:03');
```

**Which prints:**

```
select * from penguins

1   2015-01-23 15:40:36
2   
3   0000-00-00 00:00:00
4   1999-10-10 01:02:03
```

The column called `the_time` with datatype: `timestamp` in 2nd row has the value NULL.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the default value for the hireDate column. Default value should be null

This

```
create table temp(id int, hireDate timestamp default 0);
```

Should be this:

```
create table temp(id int, hireDate timestamp null);
```

Comment: `hireDate timestamp default null` is a syntax error. `hireDate timestamp null` works.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert NULL in the `hireDate` coloumn  of your table then you have to provide null

`INSERT INTO temp (id, hireDate) VALUES(3, null);`

Because `Datatype`  of `hireDate` is `timestamp` and it should be defined as null when creating column

Comment: That does not insert `null`, but rather `0000-00-00 00:00:00` with a warning as if providing any other invalid value for a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Never store any application-value into a MySQL timestamp-type column.
Use the timestamp-type only for database-server-side dynamic timestamping (see the DEFAULT and ON UPDATE column attributes).
Make that explicit, by calling the columns 'mysql_row_created_at' and 'mysql_row_updated_at'.

Be aware that MySQL physically stores its timestamp-type as a numerical UNIX-epoch-delta, so it has an implicit timezone of UTC, which makes it immune to timezone changes on the session (AKA connection) level.

Stay away from the 'datetime' type, even more so when storing any value that has a known timezone. The 'datetime' type is much like a string of packed numbers. There are no timezone details stored with that.

The 'date' type is generally fine to use. Be aware though that in some contexts it will be intepreted as a datetime at midnight (of the active timezone), which will then lead to all 'datetime' related confusions that you should avoid.

For any application-side date-time-values, use an 'int unsigned', a 'bigint' (signed), a 'double' (signed) or a decimal(N,P), to simply store UNIX-epoch-deltas.
Make sure to show the resolution in a column name suffix, if it is not seconds.

Examples:

```
`mysql_row_created_at` TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`mysql_row_updated_at` TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

`epoch` int unsigned NOT NULL,
`epoch_ms` bigint NOT NULL,
`epoch_us` bigint NOT NULL,
`epoch` double NOT NULL,
`epoch6` decimal(16,6),
```

Treat your database as much as dumb storage as possible. So do any conversions only on the application-side, never on the database-side.

Good to know about:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.TIME_ZONE
, @@SESSION.TIME_ZONE
, @@SESSION.TIMESTAMP
, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(6))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar behavior when upgrading from old mysql 5.6.44-86.0 to aurora mysql 5.7.12. The code was inserting NULL as timestamp and expecting to write an all 0 date - instead it was throwing the error "Column 'XXXX' cannot be null". I resolved the issue by setting group parameter explicit_defaults_for_timestamp to 0 which then allowed insert/update of timestamp column to null without error.