# Mysql. Update not null column with null value

Tags: mysql, sql-update

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS from users LIKE 'created_at';
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| created_at | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_strict_mode';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| innodb_strict_mode | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE `users` SET `created_at` = NULL WHERE `users`.`id` = 200;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1

mysql> SELECT `created_at` from `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 200;
+---------------------+
| created_at          |
+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is it normal behavior? Just warning.

Comment: [**Inserting null into MySQL timestamp**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489078/inserting-null-into-mysql-timestamp/12489167#12489167)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be normal  behavior. It depends on server's SQL Mode. It is possible that database is not in strict mode, and zero-dates are allowed.

See more details on this page - [Server SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html): STRICT_ALL_TABLES, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,  NO_ZERO_DATE.

Check current SQL mode using this query -

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE variable_name = 'sql_mode';
```