# How to check if a timestamp is set in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

When a timestamp column is defined as `DEFAULT 0`, if it's not specified in INSERT or UPDATE, '0000-00-00 00:00:00' becomes the default value.

What's the proper way to check if such a timestamp is set thus not the default value?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp <> 0
```

It does seem to work but I'm not sure if it's the proper way and work 100% cases?

And when such value gets selected in PHP, how to check if it's set or not?

Thus far, I came up with something like this:

```
if ($row['timestamp'] != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
}
```

It does work but it seems tacky to me. I'm not so sure if its the proper way neither. What should I do instead?

Comment: [This one ?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12489078/3282633) ?

Comment: this should work in php side  . if ($row['timestamp'] > 0) { }

Comment: @Anish, that seems the way in PHP. What about in MySQL? I guess the same?

Comment: @kavoir.com . Yes the same will work on mysql

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp > 0 . this one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Php side you can use this

```
 if ($row['timestamp'] > 0) { }
```

and

in mysql

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

If the field type is `DATETIME` it will always save `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as default. So you can check if the column is greater than `0000-00-00` -

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp > '0000-00-00'
```

Comment: Can I use `timestamp > 0` when `timestamp` column is `DATETIME`?

Comment: I would prefer to use `0000-00-00`. For this it will be treated as `NULL`.